# PHP, jQuery AJAX - 2 mysql queries

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a `mysql_query()`; and if that's successful I wan't to do another one, which has to update a field in another table.

My **mysql_query()**; code looks like this:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    if($query){
        $sqlU = mysql_query("UPDATE lookup SET lookupStatus=1 WHERE lookupId=".(int)$post['FK_lookupId']."");
        return true;
    }
```

The `$sql` which is not provided in the question is just a simple `INSERT` statement.

The `$sqlU UPDATE` statement is not even run.

P.S: I think the problem is that it's running through a jQuery AJAX, and therefore when the first `mysql_query()`; returns true, it's cutting off the rest of my PHP.

My jQuery:

```
$('#lookupAnswerGo').submit(function() {
var dataString = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLookupAnswer",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(returnedData){

        if(returnedData){
            $('.errorMessage').fadeIn().html(returnedData);
        } else {
            window.location.href = "";
        }

    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

If I'm right about the problem is AJAX, then how do I prevent it from cutting off my PHP?

Comment: AJAX doesn't 'cut off PHP', it just requests a page from the webserver just like any browser would.

Comment: Call your php-file directly (without using AJAX) and watch the result. Use 'print_r()' or 'echo' to get the content of '$query'

Comment: I just thought that AJAX could determine if the query was succesful and therefore would "jump" out of my function.

Comment: no, AJAX can't do that, it has no "special powers", it acts the same as a browser - PHP is run on the server and content is returned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try a more robust version of how to check if the first query ran, something like this:

```
  $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
  if( mysql_affected_rows() > 0 )
  {
    $sqlU = mysql_query("UPDATE lookup SET lookupStatus=1 WHERE lookupId=".(int)$post['FK_lookupId']."");
    return true;
  }
```

There is no reason why you should consider this a problem of the AJAX call. The execution of the php script only ends with php statements - i.e. return or die. AJAX itself can't determine if a query if finished or not (unless you provide an appropriate statement in php).

Comment: I'll try this when I'll get back to my computer. Thanks!